# Deserialize JSON in C# to array

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm having trouble doing deserialize a certain json I am collecting a website.

```
{
  "query": {
    "search": [
      {
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "test",
        "snippet": "test"
      },
      {
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "test2",
        "snippet": "test2"
      },
      {
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "test3",
        "snippet": "test3"
      },
      {
      "ns": 0,
      "title": "test4",
      "snippet": "test4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the class that I'm trying to deserialize into:

```
private void DesURL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = @"https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php.....";

        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

        var listaURL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Query>>(json);

    }
```

when trying to run the code of an error that this json should be deserialized into an array. Ai trying utiilizar JArray the method I need to do the deserialize before you can turn into array.

The goal is to convert the title and snippet to string in order to extract information from it.

Comment: And what does your `Query` class look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro tip for you: Select your JSON and copy it to the clipboard. Now go to Visual Studio and on the *Edit* menu, *Paste Special* and then *Paste JSON as Classes*. that will give you this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Query query { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public Search[] search { get; set; }
}

public class Search
{
    public int ns { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string snippet { get; set; }
}
```

And now you can deserialise like this:

```
var listaURL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the following classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Query query { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public Search[] search { get; set; }
}

public class Search
{
    public int ns { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string snippet { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize like this:

```
var listUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not an array. It contains a `query` object with a `search` property that has an array value.

So your class has to look something like this

```
 public class ResponseDto {
     public QueryDto Query {get; set;}
 }
 public class QueryDto {
     public IEnumerable<Query> Search {get; set;}
 }

 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryDto>(json);
 var list = data.Query.Search.ToList();
```